# Sending photo to GridView from preview page

Tags: flutter

When the user agrees to the photo, I want to send the photo back to the homepage where they can access the photo later on.

Currently, I am just opening the camera again on the PhotoPreview page when the user clicks the second button (`OutlineButton`). Instead, I want this photo to be sent to the homepage.

Here is the relevant portion of the `PhotoPreview` page

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
            context), // Go back to the camera to take the picture again
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Photo Preview')),
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(child: Image.file(File(widget.imagePath))),
        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openGallery();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Okay'),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff33333D)),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

The `Gridview` on my `home` page, which renders the photo in the format I want, is as such

```
: GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                          childAspectRatio: (80 / 150),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xff000000),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                  image: FileImage(widget.imageArray[index]),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      BlendMode.dstATop),
```

How can I connect the two, for when the user clicks the `OutlineButton` that it sends the photo on the preview page to the home screen in the format above?

Edit per answer: Here is full Homepage

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage_1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<File> imageArray;
  Homepage_1({Key key, this.imageArray}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Homepage_1State createState() => _Homepage_1State();
}

class _Homepage_1State extends State<Homepage_1> {
  var image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 40, right: 0, bottom: 0),
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(
                'App Name',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 50, bottom: 0),
                  child: widget.imageArray.isEmpty
                      ? Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            'Yikes! You have no photos',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 19,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Click the circular button below' 
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ])
                      : GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                          childAspectRatio: (80 / 150),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xff000000),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                  image: FileImage(widget.imageArray[index]),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      BlendMode.dstATop),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          })))
            ]),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

& here is full Photo preview screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class PhotoPreviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  final String imagePath;

  PhotoPreviewScreen({Key key, this.setData, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  _PhotoPreviewScreenState createState() => _PhotoPreviewScreenState();
}

class _PhotoPreviewScreenState extends State<PhotoPreviewScreen> {
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {
    if (widget.setData != null) {
      widget.setData(File(image.path));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
            context), // Go back to the camera to take the picture again
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Photo Preview')),
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(child: Image.file(File(widget.imagePath))),
        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        OutlineButton(
         onPressed: () async {
            await _openGallery();
            Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.imagePath);
          },
          child: Text('Okay'),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff33333D)),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to `pop` method and received that as a return value of `push` .

I wrote a minimal sample for you. Hopefully you get the idea, but if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask!

```
class PhotoPreviewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhotoPreviewPage({Key? key, @required this.imagePath})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhotoPreviewPageState createState() => _PhotoPreviewPageState();

  final String imagePath;
}

class _PhotoPreviewPageState extends State<PhotoPreviewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.imagePath);
          },
          child: const Text('OK'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is a overly simplified version of the CameraPage
/// Basically, you take a photo and pass that to cameraPreview page
class CameraPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final imagePath = await _takeAPhoto();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewPage(imagePath: imagePath),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('take a photo'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> _takeAPhoto() {
    // some logic to take a photo and return imagePath
    return imagePath;
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();

  final List<File> imageArray = [];
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(
          widget.imageArray.length,
          (index) => Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: FileImage(widget.imageArray[index]),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final filePath = await Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewPage(),
                ),
              );
              if (filePath != null) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.imageArray.add(File(filePath));
                });
              }
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But depending on the exact page structure of your app, you might need to look into state management solutions like Bloc or Riverpod.

Comment: Thanks! Your edit to the preview screen makes sense, but I do not understand the edit to Homepage, nor did it work when I tried. The photo should flow automatically once it is approved to the homepage, it appears that in order for the photo to come, you would need to click a button. Unless I misunderstood. I added full page code for your reference. Any thoughts??

Comment: @STyler Thanks for your edit! I actually was not sure how exactly your HomePage was configured, so made a lot of guesses there. Let me ask few questions for clarification. It appears that there is no button or any triggers that will bring up the `PhotoPreview` page, but how would user get to `PhotoPreview` page? I assumed you press a button somewhere on `HomePage` to get to `PhotoPreview` page, have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ah, that would be from my camera page. So the user clicks the button in the bottom navigation to get to the camera page, the user takes a photo, which flows to the PhotoPreview page to determine if they want to take another. If not, they can hit okay which sends photo to homepage

Comment: @STyler Thank you for you clarification. Where would HomePage fit in that flow? Is it like HomePage -> CameraPage -> PhotoPreviewPage ?

Comment: Yup. So Homepage > Camerapage > Photo Preview page > then back to Homepage if user approves of photo

Comment: @STyler Sounds good. Let me make an edit to my answer.

Comment: @STyler By the way, what does `_openGallery();` ? Do we need to call it when pressing "OK"?

Comment: We do not! :) Thanks for all the help

Comment: @STyler Makes sense!